# Custom Fields - Boolean Display of True/False to Yes/No

Tags: shortcode

I am importing fields from a Real Estate site.

The Import of one Custom Field looks like this...

Field Name after Import ---> assistedLiving Field Value ---> false

to output the display in wordpress i use this...

```
<?php 
    global $wp_query;
    $postid = $wp_query->post->ID;

    if ($immopress_property['assistedLiving']): ?>
        <li class="assistedLiving">
            <span class="attribute"  style="width:200px;display:block;float:left;"><?php echo 'Seniorengerechtes Wohnen' ; ?><span class="wpp_colon">:</span></span>
            <span class="value"><?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'assistedLiving' , true); ?>&nbsp;</span>
        </li>

        <?php wp_reset_query(); ?>
    <?php endif; ?>
```

The Result on Site looks so...

**Seniorengerechtes Wohnen:false**

I also tryed...

```
    <?php          
    if ( get_post_meta($post->ID, 'assistedLiving', true) ) { ?>

    <li class="assistedLiving">
      <span class="attribute"  style="width:200px;display:block;float:left;"><?php echo Seniorengerechtes Wohnen ; ?><span class="wpp_colon">:</span></span>
      <span class="value"><?php $assist=get_post_meta($post->ID, 'assistedLiving' , true); if ($assist=="") echo "keine Daten"; else if(strtolower($assist)=='true') echo "Ja"; else if(strtolower($assist)=='false') echo "Nein"; ?>&nbsp;</span>
    </li>

    <?php wp_reset_query(); ?>
    <?php } ?>
```

But Result on Site looks so...

**Seniorengerechtes Wohnen: **

How can i display False/True Values to display Yes/No or in German Ja/NEIN?

The Funktion to display all Field (Display it Right with yes/no):

```
function immopress_the_fields( $args ) {
    global $post, $ImmoPress;
    extract( wp_parse_args( $args, array (
        'id' => $post->ID,
        'exclude' => $exclude,
        'echo' => TRUE
    ) ), EXTR_SKIP );

    $fields = immopress_get_fields( $args );

    if ( !$fields ) 
        return false;

    $output = '';

    $output .= '<ul class="immopress-fields">';

    foreach ( $fields as $key => $value) {

        $entry = $ImmoPress->values[$value];
        if ( $entry == '') 
            $entry = $value;

        $output .= "<li class='immopress-field-$key'>";
        $output .= "<strong class='immopress-key'>{$ImmoPress->fields[$key]}: </strong>";
        $output .= "<span class='immopress-value'>$entry</span>";
        $output .= "</li>"; 
    }

    $output .= '</ul>';

    if ( $echo ) {
        echo $output;
    } else {
        return $output;
    }
```

**But i need to display only a view Custom Fields not all importet fields.**

Code for the Shortcode..

```
function immopress_fields_shortcode( $atts ) {
    $args = wp_parse_args( $atts, array (
        'echo' => FALSE
    ) );
    return immopress_the_fields( $args );       
}
add_shortcode( 'immopress_fields', 'immopress_fields_shortcode' );
```

Answer (score 1):

How about using a [ternary operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php)?

```
    if ($immopress_property['assistedLiving']): ?>
        <li class="assistedLiving">
            <span class="attribute" style="width:200px;display:block;float:left;"><?php echo 'Seniorengerechtes Wohnen' ; ?><span class="wpp_colon">:</span></span>
            <span class="value"><?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'assistedLiving' , true) ? 'Ja' : 'Nein'; ?>&nbsp;</span>
        </li>

        <?php wp_reset_query(); ?>
    <?php endif; ?>
```

Also, please, keep your [presentation separate from your content](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_presentation_and_content) by not using inline styles.

Comment: yes i try´d that too, but then it is always shown also on posts that dont have this custom field. Thats the big problem i have.

Comment: What is the exact goal? Can you elaborate a bit more?

Comment: '' !== get_post_meta(...) ? 'Ja' : 'Nein'